# Proof of $\cos(\theta) da=r^2 d\Omega$

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I'm reading through Classical Electrodynamics by Jackson and he makes use of a particular identity that I've not actually seen before. I can't seem to find a proof for it anywhere. It is just as the title says:

$\cos(\theta)da=r^2 d\Omega$

where $d\Omega$ is $\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$, the solid angle.

As an example for context consider Gauss' law. If the electric field **E** at a point on a Gaussian surface due to the charge q within the surface makes an angle $\theta$ with the unit normal, then the normal component of **E** times the area element is:

$\vec{E} \cdot \hat{n} da=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}d\Omega$

Since **E** is directed along the line from the surface element to the charge *q*, $\cos\theta da=r^2 d\Omega$, where $d\Omega$ is the element of solid angle sutended by *da* at the position of the charge. Therefore,

$\vec{E} \cdot \hat{n} da=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}d\Omega$.

A simple geometric proof is all I need, I just want to know where this comes from.

Comment: I believe this would be more suitable for a physics forum. That said, how do your variables-$\theta, r, \Omega $-relate?

Comment: Contextualize the question. Can you show us a an equation/step where he uses this equality?

Comment: also what is da?

Comment: And now there is also a $\phi$ :-)..

Comment: edited with all that in mind. da is not specified in the book, that's part of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

I suppose that you found the formula in the context of Gauss Theorem. If so then this figure (from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170708054352/http://www.kshitij-iitjee.com/deriving-Gauss%E2%80%99s-law)) shows how to find the formula.

[image]

Comment: Bless you, I was losing my mind because of this for about an hour and I found your answer